# Why $\frac{p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)}{|p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)|}$ defines a loop in the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, parametrization

Why can $$\frac{p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)}{|p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)|}$$

defines a loop in the unit circle $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ based at 1, where $s\in[0,1]$, $p(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ is a polynomial for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $p(z)\neq0$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

I understand the fact that dividing by the magnitude is rescaling it the unit size but what I struggle to grasp is why $p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)$ is a circle? Is there any way to understand this parametrisation?

I know $re^{2\pi is}$ is parametrisation of a circle with radius $r$, but what does it actually say when we put in the points of the circle into the polynomial $p(z)$?

My other doubt is could $p(re^{2\pi is})/|p(re^{2\pi is})|$ also define a loop in the unit circle? What is the purpose of the $p(r)$ in the original formula?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your function $f(s)$.  For it to be a loop, you just need to have $f(0)=f(1)$.  This is true because $e^{2\pi i}=e^{0}=1$, so $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are both $\frac{p(r)/p(r)}{|p(r)/p(r)|}=1$.

Comment: But does that mean $p(re^{2\pi is})/|p(re^{2\pi is})|$ can also do the job? Why do we still need $p(r)$?

Comment: I would guess that in context you want it to be a loop based at $1$, so $f(0)=f(1)=1$.  If you leave out $p(r)$, you'll get $f(0)=f(1)=p(r)/|p(r)|$.

Comment: So why if we include $p(r)$ we would get a circle?

Comment: What don't you understand about what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: I understand that if I leave out $p(r)$ I'll get $p(r)/|p(r)|$ and it is a loop based at 1. What I don't understand is what makes the difference if we don't leave out $p(r)$? Why can we get a circle if we don't leave out $p(r)$?

Comment: We do still get a loop if we leave out $p(r)$, it just (probably) won't satisfy $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

Comment: Another thing that I still doubt is that if we don't leave out $p(r)$, how can we guarantee that the shape of the loop is a circle?

Comment: What does "the shape of the loop is a circle" mean?  The image will be (contained in) the unit circle, but beyond that there's not any meaningful sense in which it will be a circle in general.